# Editing Links in the Footer of WordPress Themes with Base64 Encrypted Code?

Tags: themes

Some WordPress themes have their links encrypted in the footer and I am not able to edit them if I want to edit the links. This is the example code I found:

> `<?php`
>   `eval(base64_decode('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'));?>`

Does any one know how to find the footer link we want from them and edit them?

Comment: What theme is this from? Where is that code? Is editing the footer link in that theme against any kind of terms of service/end user license agreement you had to agree to in order to use the theme?

Comment: The theme is from wordpressthemesbase.com .They have not mentioned any Terms and conditions page on their website.So I hope there is no Obligation in editing the footer file.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and kick that crap away. Themes with eval are robbing your time if you're not a programming pro so just trash it. Really. Don't let yourself fooled.

Comment: +1 for what @hakre said. Themes from that site are mostly exact copies of themes on wp.org with the addition of the crap in the footer or worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is the output from that function:

```
?>      

        <div class="clear"></div>



    </div>

    <!-- /Main -->



    <!-- Footer -->

    <div id="footer">

    <?php the_time('Y'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> .  WordPress . <?php if(is_home()) : ?><a href="http://wordpressthemesforfree.com/" title="Wordpress themes">Wordpress themes</a><?php endif; ?></div>

    <!-- Footer -->



</div></div></div>

<!-- /Page -->





<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>



</html> <?
```

So, if you want to get rid of that base64 encoded line, and use this, do it. I think that was just their way of keeping total non-programmers from messing with the attribution links. If the theme is GPL licensed, then you are under no obligation to keep any part of that code there.

And there's a pretty strong case to be made that themes are GPL by their very nature (which is not to say the other side doesn't have strong arguments too. However, as Mike pointed out in the comments, this question will not be answered until someone litigates, so let's just leave that whole argument out of this question).

EDIT

To get the above output, I did this:

```
<pre>
<?php

$out = base64_decode('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');

echo str_replace( '<', '&lt;', $out );

?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply !
It solves my problem :)
I would like to know that how can I get an output like above with other themes If I would like to use them .There are some other themes with the similar codes at their footer .
Some joomla Templates too have the same type of footer files.

Comment: Added how I did that.

Comment: Since WordPress themes are derived from the WordPress code (they can't function on their own in any way and depend on core functionality), they're also GPL licensed by their very nature.  Adding encoded text to the footer is theme developer's attempt to keep their attribution links in your footer and prevent you from redistributing the code minus their copyright - I'm sure it's meant with the best of intentions, but it still violates the terms of the GPL ...

Comment: @user391 if John's answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted (by clicking the check mark next to it).

Comment: @EAMann - You are stating the position of many GPL advocates include ma.tt but it's only a position, it has never been litigated so it is no definitive that a non-GPL theme would  violate the GPL, at least not legally. I've asked the opinion of a prominent local IP attorney who looked at this in depth and his opinion was that non-GPL themes in fact did not violate the GPL. Unfortunately it won't be cleared up unless litigated.

Comment: I think we should keep GPL discussions to a minimum, since it is both divisive and not germane to the issue at hand, namely, how to edit the footer text if necessary.

Comment: @John P Bloch - Love the edit and I **completely** agree about the GPL; that subject should only be addressed on questions specifically about the GPL. Everyone else agreed?

Comment: As tempted as I am to keep arguing, I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

The technical answer is: Remove the eval code from the theme and replace it with your own one. Or debug the eval code, but I assume that's out of your scope.

The realistic answer I would give is that you should consider to decide to not get fooled any longer (and to not bother others with that crap you downloaded). Get a real theme with clean code and not such a pile of shit. Are you interested for how that shit is licensed? I am not!  Just trash it and start a real life and site.

Comment: I am Sorry If my question bothered you and others .I like these themes downloaded form wordpressthemesbase and I wanted to use them knowing what behind the encrypted code and edit the footer .

Comment: You like sites the steal themes are re-package them as malware?

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I've seen Base64 show up where it never belonged. The result of a hack. I use a number of themes and have more on my home drive than I'll ever use, and none have it as part of their code. 
I suggest you go back to the theme itself before you loaded it, or if you instated through the admin page and not through FTP, find it on the developer's site and download. See if it's there (the base64). If not, you've been hacked.